# How to use multiple conditions with SUM, QUERY, & IMPORTRANGE in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am having an issue where Sheets is giving me errors any time I add more than one condition. It just won't let me no matter what I do. I am try to sum up imported cells from a different sheet based on a couple conditions.

**What am I doing wrong here?** Should this work based on what is written?

```
=SUM(
IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1pgXsD_fAm6Sw0sFkxQWKpZKzKADg2ojVreMDCq2ebqs#gid=384994158", "All SEO Projects!a2:ac"),
  "select Col14 where Col17 contains 'Y'",0))+
IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1pgXsD_fAm6Sw0sFkxQWKpZKzKADg2ojVreMDCq2ebqs#gid=384994158", "All SEO Projects!a2:ad"),
  "select Col13 where Col30 contains 'N' and where not Col1 contains 'Past Due'",0)),
)
```

Comment: Have you tried the Importrange out from the IFERROR??, maybe you haven't linked the sheets yet and you wouldn't know if it's wrapped between IFERROR

Comment: If I remove the iferror I get a giant error on everything. I only put that in case one of the cells return empty. The sheets are linked, I only get an issue when I add multiple conditions on that second importrange..

Comment: With SUM you wouldn't have trouble with empty values, so maybe I'd suggest to remove the IFERRORs to start "debugging" it. Query wouldn't return an error if no values met the conditions either. Start with `=SUM(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1pgXsD_fAm6Sw0sFkxQWKpZKzKADg2ojVreMDCq2ebqs#gid=384994158", "All SEO Projects!a2:ac"),"select Col14 where Col17 contains 'Y'",0),QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1pgXsD_fAm6Sw0sFkxQWKpZKzKADg2ojVreMDCq2ebqs#gid=384994158", "All SEO Projects!a2:ad"),"select Col13 where Col30 contains 'N' and where not Col1 contains 'Past Due'",0))` and tell us what you see

Comment: Can you add more details as well as your desired output with a dummy sheet on your question? Remove sensitive information, if any.